# Partitioning data using data windowing in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data that I need to analyse. I am trying to work out how to use a for loop to partition the data into 5 - 10 second blocks. I am very new to MatLab and have no idea how i would go about doing this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post more information about your data, or possibly an example set, to exemplify what you need.

Comment: 39297.0 981.0 2204.0 1923.0
39937.0 1003.0 2193.0 1955.0
40577.0 995.0 2172.0 1939.0
41217.0 952.0 2196.0 1911.0
41857.0 953.0 2167.0 1964.0
42497.0 967.0 2191.0 1943.0
43137.0 1012.0 2159.0 1938.0
This is a sample of the data I have collected it was collected using a Shimmer device. The data fields are time stamp, Accelerometer X, Accelerometer Y and Accelerometer Z. I am trying to plot this data and then focus in on certain parts of the plotted graph.

Comment: Sorry the data should have show as four columns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a vector of samples `x`, and a sampling frequency `fs` (in Hz), then you can first reshape your vector into a matrix:

```
x = reshape(x, fs*W, []);
```

where `W` is the window length (in seconds).  Each column in now a separate window of data.<sup>1</sup>

You can then process each window (i.e. each column) in turn:

```
for i = 1:size(x,2)
    process(x(:,i));
end
```

---

<sub>1. This assumes that `x` contains an exact integer number of windows.</sub>